# Pasting Timestamp Into Final Row of Column

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp, range

My goal with the following macro is to copy columns A to F that correspond to the row of the active cell, paste the data from these columns into the worksheet "Day 1", and in the first blank row of column G in the destination sheet, paste a timestamp.

In the following code I could only manage to copy the entire row of the active cell.  The timestamp is pasted in random rows in column G of the destination sheet.  Most of the time, it copies nothing.

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

```
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Day 1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Range("G2").Value = Now()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":F" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy Sheets("Day 1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

As for the timestamp, don't forget to reference the "Day 1" sheet.

```
Sheets("Day 1").Range("G2").Value = Now
```

The way you had it, you were inserting the timestamp into your *current* worksheet (*NOT* "Day 1").  My guess is that every time Row 2 happened to be the active row, you copied that entire row (along with the **G2** timestamp) into the next empty row of the "Day 1" sheet.  That's why the timestamp was appearing in "random" rows all over.

**UPDATE:**

```
dim NextRow as Long

NextRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":F" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy Sheets("Day 1").Range("A" & NextRow)
Sheets("Day 1").Range("G" & NextRow).Value = Now
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  You were very correct about referencing "Day 1" (made that change).  I'm looking to paste the time stamp in the last row of column G in the destination table (same row the data is copied to).  How would I adjust the range in the following code:  Sheets("Day 1").Range("G"&lastRow).Value = Now  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Updated the answer for you.  Give it a try and let me know how it works for you.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks so much!!  I tweaked NextRow with the following so I'm referencing the "Day 1" worksheet:  NextRow = Sheets("Day 1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row   Works like a charm!

Comment: Nice catch.  You're absolutely right!  Happy to help.